# Out of memory error grails

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

I get the following errors on running application:

```
  Warning:(415, 32) java: PrimaryKeyInd in homebase.meta.MetaAttribute has been deprecated
  Warning:(19, 32) java: org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer in org.apache.xml.serialize has been deprecated
  Warning:(8, 38) java: org.apache.commons.collections.MultiHashMap in org.apache.commons.collections has been deprecated
  Warning:(1431, 22) java: getAttribute(java.lang.String) in homebase.SQL_Instance has been deprecated
 Information:java: Some input files additionally use or override a deprecated API.
 Information:java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

And at the end I get `Memory GC error`,anyone has idea why?

Comment: These are just warnings (because of using depracated methods). Is there any seer error later?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Error:Groovyc: Internal groovyc error: code 1 .Information:Groovyc: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:622)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)

Comment: It's a common problem. You should increase limit of a memory used by Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Increase memory used by Intellij. Click **File** -> **Settings** and then:

[image]